# Centos /usr readonly

Tags: centos, rpm, readonly

I have some rpm to install on my centos 4.8, but when I try to install the rpm as root (rpm -i), the output said /usr and all subdirectory are read-only.
I tried to create a file : touch /usr/testFile as root and the /usr is read-only.

What should I do to install my package?

Edit: mount -l
/dev/sda6 on /usr type ext3 (ro,nodev) [/usr]

Thanks you.

Comment: Is /usr or / mounted as a read-only file system? use mount -l to check whether the file system is read-only or not

Comment: I edit my question with the result of your command. Thanks

Comment: I've got your problem, your /usr directory has been mounted as read-only file system. You could solve this by edit /etc/fstab and restart system. Could you please show me your /etc/fstab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the solution:

edit /etc/fstab

find line contains /usr

change ro to rw

restart computer

Comment: With `mount -o rw,remount /usr/` no need to restart, but it's not persistent across restart.